# Ruby: How to create an array by combining and interleaving two other arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

Probably, to make a more general question is how to do list comprehension in Ruby.

Let's say given a number N (say N=5) I want to get an array like this:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Using imperative way I can do:

```
  arr = []
  N = 5
  (0..N-1).each do |i|
    (i+1..N-1).each do |j|
      arr << [i, j]
    end
  end
  puts arr
```

Using functional way:

```
(0..N-1).collect{|el1| (el1+1..N-1).collect{|el2| [el1, el2]}}.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
```

I don't like that the second example relies on the fact that the array is sorted in the  right order.
Is there a cleaner way to get the array in a functional way (without the extra flatten and slice)?

Answer (score 2):

I would do as below :

```
n = 5
a = n.times.flat_map do |i|
  [i].product (i+1..n-1).to_a
end
a # => [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Arup! flat_map is the key here: we can also do it like: (0..N-1).flat_map{|el1| (el1+1..N-1).map{|el2| [el1, el2]}}

Comment: Also the product function is very powerful when it comes to combining arrays. I used it before to get all permutations of two numbers each coming from an array. Very beautiful application here, Arup, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
Array(0...N).combination(2).to_a
```

which looks nice, but has the disadvantage that it generates N!/(4*(N-2)!) combinations it doesn't use.

Edit: I originally had `select { |x,y| x < y }` in place of `to_a` in the above. @Stefan pointed out that `select` is supurfluous.  Maybe I had `permutation(2)` on the brain.

Here's another way, a variant of @Arup's answer:

```
a = Array(0...N)
a.size.times.reduce([]) { |b,_| b + [a.shift].product(a) }
```

Comment: Doesn't `(0...5).to_a.combination(2).to_a` return the same array?

Comment: @Stefan make it as an answer..  Good one!

Comment: To be more precise: isn't the `.select { |x,y| x < y }` part superfluous?

Comment: Thanks, Cary. Actually the combination without select works too: Array(0...N).combination(2).to_a

Comment: @CarySwoveland `Array(0...N).combination(2).to_a` is enough and better!

Comment: @Stefan make your original comment and answer and feel free to copy my benchmark data, and I'll delete my answer. As far as I can tell, it is the fastest/most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way to do it is Stefan's, which was a comment to Cary's answer (modified to use `n` variable in Arup's comment to this answer), which was a modification from Cary's answer, so +1 to all those guys:

```
2.1.0p0 :001 > n = 5
 => 5 
2.1.0p0 :002 > a = (0...n).to_a.combination(2).to_a
 => [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Some benchmarks:

```
2.1.0p0 :001 > require 'benchmark'
 => true 
2.1.0p0 :002 > n = 5
 => 5 
2.1.0p0 :003 > puts Benchmark.measure { 1000000.times { a = n.times.flat_map {|i| [i].product (i+1..n-1).to_a} } }
  8.050000   0.010000   8.060000 (  8.051535)
 => nil 
2.1.0p0 :004 > puts Benchmark.measure { 1000000.times { a = n.times.flat_map {|x| (x+1..n-1).map{|y| [x,y]}} } }
  6.250000   0.000000   6.250000 (  6.249600)
 => nil
2.1.0p0 :005 > puts Benchmark.measure { 1000000.times { a = Array(0...n).combination(2).select { |x,y| x < y } } }
  5.110000   0.010000   5.120000 (  5.120506)
 => nil 
2.1.0p0 :006 > puts Benchmark.measure { 1000000.times { a = n.times.to_a.combination(2).to_a } }
  4.050000   0.000000   4.050000 (  4.045895)
 => nil 
2.1.0p0 :007 > puts Benchmark.measure { 1000000.times { a = Array(0...n).combination(2).to_a } }
  3.920000   0.000000   3.920000 (  3.928282)
 => nil 
2.1.0p0 :008 > puts Benchmark.measure { 1000000.times { a = (0...n).to_a.combination(2).to_a } }
  3.520000   0.000000   3.520000 (  3.522056)
 => nil
```

Comment: Arup - what you just said is faster as well- just benchmarked it and changed the answer.